# How to get missing values in row order?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

In a table, many rows have been deleted, how to get the id of missing rows for next `INSERT`?

For example

```
id      col1
1       1
3       3
4       4
5       5
8       8
9       9
```

how can I get the value of first available id for next `INSERT`. Here I want to get the `id = 2`.

Something like

```
SELECT id+1 FROM table WHERE CLAUSE // pointing to the least available value
// or x = id +1 (after SELECT)
INSERT INTO table (id, ....) VALUES ('x', ....)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Why is having gaps in the id sequence a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the column is just a surrogate key and is not used for other purposes (display sorting and so forth) then I would just use your database's `AUTOINCREMENT` equivalent and ignore the fact that there will be gaps in the IDs, as there point is to be unique rather than serving other purposes. The much recommended "SQL Anti-Patterns" book has a chapter on this entitled "pseudokey neat-freak". *This depends on what you are modelling and how of course, if the numbers do carry meaning beyond being an identifier then this point is irrelevant.*

The general concept you want to read around (it is worth a little background reading as these problems crop up all over the place so knowing how to spot them and deal with them efficiently or design them out is very useful) is **gaps and islands**. There are many online references about this ([this is the first one a quick search found](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), it is talking about MSSQL but the concepts are transferable).

As well as the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` method, which is usually suggested as the way the code reads makes your intentions more obvious, you can also do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.id-1
FROM     yourtable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         yourtable t2 
ON       t2.id=t1.id-1 -- will match if there is a row with the next ID down from the row in t1
WHERE    t2.id IS NULL -- the next ID down not found
AND      t1.id > 0     -- assume 1 is the lowest valid ID
ORDER BY t1.id
```

(that is MSSQL syntax, you may need to tweak it)
Both variants *should* produce similar query plans so perform the same, but I've seen the above approach perform better as part of a more complex query so it may be worth trying both in your circumstances and verifying which performs best.

Also not that neither method as currently presented will return the first ID if the table is empty: you'll get no rows back instead (or NULL if you are using this as a sub-query). One method of getting around this is to have an "invalid" row with `id=0` but that is quite dirty (you end up having to filter that out of many other queries) so dealing with the nothing/NULL in your logic instead instead is strongly recommended. For tables that will never be empty in production (a users table for instance, even on initial install there will be one record for the initial setup/admin user) this or course is not an issue.

*edit:* Corrected the query to return the first ID if not found, as ypercube noted the first version would not do

**Newer mySQL Versions**

Since this answer, mySQL and MariaDB have added support for window functions (in versions 8 and 10.2 respectively) such as `LAG()` and `LEAD()`. You can use these to inspect the next (or previous) row and compare the value that is intended to increment and see if there is a gap, meaning you do not need to join the table onto itself or use a sub-query with `EXISTS` for this comparison - with the right index(es) this can be a much more efficient way to implement some gap/island queries.

All the common SQL database engines (sqlite, postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, ...) now support window functions.

Comment: In MySQL you can use `LIMIT` (after `ORDER BY`) instead of `TOP`. If the missing id values are in the beginning (1,2,3...), the query will not show `1` as answer, right?.

Comment: Good point, that will never find the first number in sequence. Also it will just return NULL if the table is empty instead of returning the first valid number.

Comment: I've edited the query to fix that. Also it (sill) will just return nothing (therefore NULL if used in a sub-query) if the table is empty, rather than returning the first valid number (the other examples have the same issue).

Answer (score 4):

You can get a first available `id` with a query like this

```
SELECT id + 1 available_id
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1
   WHERE id = t.id + 1
)
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
| AVAILABLE_ID |
|--------------|
|            2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a1f8/5)** demo

---

To insert

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, ...)
SELECT id + 1, <some_value>, ...
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1
   WHERE id = t.id + 1
)
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fabcef/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use user-defined variables. Not best solution but it can be useful.

```
set @raw_number = (select ID - 1
from names
LIMIT 1);
select @raw_number as RESULT
from names
where ID > @raw_number := @raw_number + 1
LIMIT 1;
```